# Show that the closure of $C_c(X)$ is $C_0(X)$.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological Hausdorff space. By $C_b(X)$ denote the continuous bounded function $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$, by $C_c(X)$ the continuous functions $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ which have compact support $\text{supp}f=\overline{\left\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\right\}}$ and, finally, by $C_0(X)$ denote the continuous functions $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ that vanish at infinity.

> > Show that the closure of $C_c(X)$ with respect to the Banachspace $(C_b(X),\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty})$ is $C_0(X)$, i.e.
> >     $$
> > \overline{C_c(X)}=C_0(X).
> > $$

I think the inclusion "$\subseteq$" is the easier one.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary and let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $C_c(X)$ that converges to $f$ w.r.t. to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}$. This implies uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$. Hence, $f$ is continuous. Moreover, there exists some $N(\varepsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert < \varepsilon~\forall n\geq N(\varepsilon)
$$
for all $x\in X$. For all $x\notin\text{supp}f_{N(\varepsilon)}$, $f_{N(\varepsilon)}(x)=0$, hence
$$
\lvert f(x)\rvert=\lvert f(x)-f_{N(\varepsilon)}\rvert <\varepsilon
$$
for all $x\notin\text{supp}f_{N(\varepsilon)}$.

This means that $f\in C_0(X)$.

---

Now, I do not know exactly how to prove "$\supseteq$". I guess the general idea is the following. Let $f\in C_0(X)$. Now, construct a sequence $(\varphi_n)$ in $C_c(X)$ with $\varphi_n\to f$ w.r.t. the supremum norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}$.

Comment: Let $\varphi_n = f\chi_{[-n,n]}$, then $$\|f-\varphi_n\|_\infty = \|f\chi_{(-\infty,n)\ \cup\ (n,\infty)}\|_\infty\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0.$$

Comment: @Math1000: Why should $\varphi_n$ be continuous?

Comment: @carmichael561 You mentioned before that it might be necessary to have local compactness. Looking here http://planetmath.org/sites/default/files/texpdf/41281.pdf (Corollary 2 which uses the Urysohn-Lemma that needs local compactness) seems to confirm your comment. I'll ask the author of the task if this might be assumed.

Comment: Sorry, $[-n,n]$ would be $\{x\in X: \|x\|\leqslant n\}$, but you are correct, that function would be continuous on the compact set, not on all of $X$.

Comment: @ Rhjg: That was my initial impression, but now I'm not sure. I would definitely ask.

Comment: @Math1000 $\{ x \in X : \| x \| \leqslant n \}$ still makes no sense because $X$ is an arbitrary Hausdorff topological space, not a normed vector space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you need to assume that $X$ is locally compact:

Let $f\in C_{0}\left(X\right)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Note that $U:=\left\{ x\in X\,\mid\,\left|f\left(x\right)\right|>\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\} $
is open with closure $\overline{U}\subset\left\{ x\in X\,\mid\,\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\} $,
which is compact as a closed subset of a compact set. Furthermore,
$K:=\left\{ x\in X\,|\,\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\geq\varepsilon\right\} $
is a compact subset of $U$, so that the Urysohn-Lemma (applied to
the compact Hausdorff space $\overline{U}$, with $U\subset\overline{U}$
open and $K\subset U$ compact) yields $\varphi\in C(\overline{U})$
with $\varphi|_{K}\equiv1$, $0\leq\varphi\leq1$ and $\operatorname{supp}\varphi\subset U$,
where the closure for the support is taken in $\overline{U}$.

Now,
define
$$
g:X\to\left[0,1\right],x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0, & x\in X\setminus U,\\
\varphi\left(x\right), & x\in\overline{U}.
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $X\setminus U$ and $\overline{U}$ are both closed, so
that $g$ is continuous by the gluing lemma (note that $g$ is well-defined,
since for $x\in\left(X\setminus U\right)\cap\overline{U}$, we have
$\varphi\left(x\right)=0$ since $\operatorname{supp}\varphi\subset U$.

Thus, $g$ has compact support (in fact $\operatorname{supp}g=\operatorname{supp}\varphi$),
so that the same is true of $\tilde{f}:=g\cdot f\in C_{c}\left(X\right)$.
It is not hard to see $\left\Vert \tilde{f}-f\right\Vert _{\sup}\leq\varepsilon$.

Comment: I guess with 'gluing lemma' you mean this one: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Gluing_lemma_for_closed_subsets ? I've never heard of it but it seems to be well-known and very important.

Comment: @Rhjg Munkres calls it the "pasting lemma."

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks, I found it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma  -- it's a nice statement I did not know before..

Comment: Why is $\left\{ x\in X\,\mid\,\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}$ compact?

Comment: @PhoemueX I thought that $C_c$ was the collection of functions with compact support, whereas $C_0$ was the collection of functions which vanish at infinity. Vanishing at infinity doesn't imply compact support, right?

Comment: @user193319: Yes, you are right, sorry about that. Still, vanishing at infinity means that the set you are asking about is compact, by definition. See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanish_at_infinity