# Mistake in proof of $\overline{C_c(X)} = C_0(X)$..

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Usually one employs Urysohn's Lemma to proof the above identity.

See for example here in the first answer: [Show that the closure of $C_c(X)$ is $C_0(X)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729323/show-that-the-closure-of-c-cx-is-c-0x)

I find that proof rather complicated compared to the following one.

Additionally in the proof in the link we need $X$ to be Hausdorff.

Now I've seen the following proof which does not use any property of $X$ and is quite simple aswell. It doesn't even have to be a Hausdorff-space. This is weird to me and I think there must be a mistake in it but I can't find it.

> $f\in C_0(x)$. Define $f_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases}0\quad &\text{if }|f(x)|< \epsilon\\ f(x)-\epsilon\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}\quad &\text{if }|f(x)|\geq \epsilon.\end{cases}$
>
> $f_\epsilon \to f$ uniformly follows immidiately by distinguishing cases if $|f(x)|$ is bigger or smaller than $\epsilon$.
>
> Additionally $f_\epsilon$ has compact support because $\{|f|\geq \epsilon\}$ is compact.
>
> By the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma $f_\epsilon$ is continuous.

If this really would be correct, I wonder why this simple and more general proof isn't the one one usually sees.

---

Edit: As requested, more details:

> 1) $f_\epsilon\to f$ uniformly: Let $x\in X$. If $|f(x)|<\epsilon$, then $|f(x)-f_\epsilon(x)| = |f(x)|<\epsilon$. If $|f(x)|\geq \epsilon$ then $|f(x)-f_\epsilon(x)| = \epsilon\left|\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}\right| = \epsilon$, hence $\|f-f_\epsilon\|_\infty\leq \epsilon$.
>
> 2) $\{|f|\geq \epsilon\}$ is compact: Since $f\in C_0(X)$, there is compact $A\subset X$ with $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ if $x\notin A$, therefore $\{|f|\geq \epsilon\}\subseteq A$ and $\{|f|\geq \epsilon\}$ is a closed subset of a compact set and therefore compact.

Comment: “follows immidiately” can you do it immediately?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, i edited my question.

Comment: Yeah, the proof seems to be correct.

Comment: I do not think $\{|f|\ge\epsilon\}=\text{supp} f_{\epsilon}$, if $|f(x)|=\epsilon$ then $f_{\epsilon}=0$, so $\text{supp} f_{\epsilon}=\{x:|f(x)|\ge\epsilon\}\setminus \{x:|f(x)|=\epsilon\}=\{x:|f(x)|>\epsilon\}$, is it true?

Comment: @xunitc That is a good point. The support of $f_\epsilon$ would be the closure of the set that you mentioned and it would remain to show that this is the same as the set i mentioned. I think this is the case but i am too long out of mathematics now to say this with confidence sadly. It could well be that you are right and this is indeed an error in the proof.

Comment: I though about this a little bit more and think now, my argument still works. We definitely have $\mathrm{supp}f_\epsilon \subset \{|f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$. So it is a closed subset of a compact set, hence itself compact. I dont know if the two sets are equal, but i think this is not necessary for the argument.