# Finite signed measures: reconcile different types of convergence

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence, borel-measures, riesz-representation-theorem

Let

- $X$ be a metric space,
- $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of all Borel signed measures on $X$,
- $\mathcal C_b(X)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions,
- $\mathcal C_0(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions that vanish at infinity, and
- $\mathcal C_c(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions with compact supports.

I'm reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4367716/1019043) about different types of convergence. Below is my understanding. Could you verify if it is fine?

---

Notice that $\mathcal M (X)$ [is a real Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440407/the-space-of-finite-signed-measures-with-the-total-variation-norm-is-a-banach-sp/4440408#4440408) with total variation norm. Also, $\mathcal C_b(X)$ and $\mathcal C_0(X)$ are real Banach space with supremum norm. Below we use the kind of [topology induced by dual pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_system#Weak_topology). Because
$$
\mathcal C_c(X) \subset \mathcal C_0(X) \subset \mathcal C_b(X),
$$
we have

1. $$
   \sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_c(X)) \subset \sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_0(X)) \subset \sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_b (X)).
   $$
2. $\sigma(\mathcal C_c(X),\mathcal M(X))$ and $\sigma(\mathcal C_0(X),\mathcal M(X))$ are the subspace topologies that $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_b (X))$ induce on $\mathcal C_c(X), \mathcal C_0(X)$ respectively.

The closure of $\mathcal C_c(X)$ in $\mathcal C_b(X)$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729323/show-that-the-closure-of-c-cx-is-c-0x) $\mathcal C_0(X)$, so
$$
\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_c(X)) = \sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_0(X)).
$$

Usually, $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_b(X))$ and $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_0(X))$ are called the **weak** and **weak$^*$** topologies of $\mathcal M(X)$ respectively. We have $\mathcal M (X)$ can be [isometrically embedded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923330/duality-pairing-between-finite-signed-measures-and-bounded-continuous-functions) into the [continuous dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Continuous_dual_space) $(\mathcal C_0 (X))^*$ of $\mathcal C_0 (X)$, so
$$
\sigma(\mathcal C_0 (X), \mathcal M(X)) \subset \sigma(\mathcal C_0 (X), (\mathcal C_0 (X))^*).
$$

If $X$ is locally compact, then $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(\mathcal C_0 (X))^*$ by [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500358/3-versions-of-riesz-markov-kakutani-theorem) and thus

1. $$
   \sigma(\mathcal C_0 (X), \mathcal M(X)) = \sigma(\mathcal C_0 (X), (\mathcal C_0 (X))^*).
   $$
2. $\sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_0(X))$ and $\sigma((\mathcal C_0 (X))^*, \mathcal C_0(X))$ have exactly the same [topological properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong in saying that

> The closure of $\mathcal C_c(X)$ in $\mathcal C_b(X)$ [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729323/show-that-the-closure-of-c-cx-is-c-0x) $\mathcal C_0(X)$, so
> $$
> \sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_c(X)) = \sigma(\mathcal M(X), \mathcal C_0(X)).
> $$

In fact, if the mass escapes at infinity, then above statement is false. In fact, we have below theorem from the paper [Vague and weak convergence of signed measures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.13207.pdf) of Martin Herdegen, Gechun Liang, and Osian Shelley, i.e.,

> **Proposition 1.3.** Let $\Omega$ be locally compact and $\left\{\mu_n\right\} \cup\{\mu\} \subset \mathcal{M}(\Omega)$ with $\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left\|\mu_n\right\|<\infty$. Then
> $I_{\mu_n}(f) \rightarrow I_\mu(f)$ for all $f \in C_0(\Omega) \quad$ if and only if $\quad I_{\mu_n}(f) \rightarrow I_\mu(f)$ for all $f \in C_c(\Omega)$.